# How do I get the distance between 2 actors in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx

How do I get X the distance between 2 actors in LibGDX?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: -1 Does not show research effort. [This is the first result of a google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026407/how-to-find-distance-beetwen-two-objects-in-libgdx).

Comment: Been a while since I've used the Scene2D scenegraph, but best guess is that Actor has a "getX," and a "getY" method used to retrieve its position. Just get the positions of both your actors, store them in variables, and use the Distance Formula (any of the several variations).

Comment: I would like to apply the x between 2 actors to a OrthographicCameras zoom

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically you want to use the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) e.g. `java.lang.Math.abs(x1-x2)` will give you what you want.

Comment: Nope not working is saying there is no applicable mothod to (float, float)

Comment: This gives you distance on one axis only. For Pythagoras' theorem it doesn't matter whether the input values are positive or negative as they are squared which makes them positive anyway.